# How to use logstash and slf4j at android

Tags: android, logstash, slf4j

I want to aggregate android's log to central.
Currently, my android app is saving it's log to local storage by slf4j.

By searching I found Bugfender which is commerical sw.
and found open source at below.
https://github.com/Labgoo/android-logstash-logger

But I'm not sure how can I aggregate my android logs.
What is the best practice for aggregating android devices's log files to central server?

Comment: Why do you want the log for all the devices that are using your app?

Comment: My android app is used specific company users only, but in play store.
Total devices my app installed about 50 devices.
When some error happend in my logic, I want to know immediately.

Comment: Here is configuration for Logstash on Android: [LogstashAndroid](https://gist.github.com/PatrykGala/55603fe4259d812fdc0ffbc9e63eaabc)